# Spring annotation

Tags: spring, annotations

When we use annotations in spring? when is th need of using annotation in spring?

I need to know when we have to use annotation. At what time we have to use annotation in spring. What is the purpose of annoatation. Please help on this

Comment: This is all you need: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/index.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.